# Standalone Django ORM - default settings not recognized

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a typical Django web app. I want to create a separate project, with its own virtualenv, and make use of the ORM to create new entries in the DB.

There are a lot of resources on explaining how to do this, including [this entry from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage). So I wrote a script as follows:

```
# Add Django project directory to path, so that I can
# import the models
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/django/project")

# Import my settings file from the Django project
from django_proj import settings as django_settings

import django
from django.conf import settings
if not settings.configured:
    settings.configure(django_settings)
django.setup()
```

When I try to run it this way, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LOGGING_CONFIG'
```

I believe this is due to the fact that I don't specify a `LOGGING_CONFIG` explicitly in my settings. I rely on the default value.

My configuration clearly works when I run it via `python manage.py`. What is the issue with this additional setup that's causing problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
import os
import sys
import django
sys.path.append('/path/to/django_project')
#from django_project import *
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_project.settings')
django.setup()
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps

Comment: I don't think the `from django_project import *` is necessary here.

Comment: That's possible. Didn't tried it without that line, since it's just an old snippet from long time ago when i also wanted to use the django ORM as standalone.

Answer (score 4):

When you say

```
settings.configure(django_settings)
```

it is the same as

```
settings.configure(default_settings=django_settings)
```

so you are telling Django to use `django_settings` for the defaults, instead of `django.conf.global_settings`. The [Django docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings) that you shouldn't normally have to do this, and in your case it's causing errors because you haven't set a default for `LOGGING`.

The easiest way to configure your script to use your settings with Django's defaults, is to set the environment variable, as in @BigZ's answer.

Comment: Ah, got it! Thanks, I thought passing the argument was the same as setting the environment variable. In these cases, I prefer passing arguments directly instead of going through environment variables. But as of now, it seems like the only way to do it is via ENV variables, right? Is this because this is better form?

Comment: It is possible to specify individual settings e.g. `settings.configure(DEBUG=TRUE, TEMPLATES=[...])`, but I don't think it's possible to import a settings file or specify its path instead of setting the environment variable. I don't know why this is the case.

Comment: This is useful to make unittests independent from each other. BigZ's answer with os.environ.setdefault() would cause side-effects if pytest collects multiple test modules that expect different settings.